# Combine different style tags in one userControl resource

Tags: winforms, wpf-controls

I'm building a userControl from 2 xaml files, one of them inherits from window class and the other from userControl class, the reason I'm doing this is to embed the WPF in a winForm. I'm merging the resources elements from both files in the new xaml file resources element, so I have two style elements as follows (The first one from userControl xaml, and the sceond one from window xaml):

```
<UserControl.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="NodeBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding Path=NodeHeight, Mode=OneTime}" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
                <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="{Binding Path=NodeWidth, Mode=OneTime}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=HasCircularDependency, Mode=OneTime}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:NodeConnector}">
            <Setter Property="ArrowLength" Value="12" />
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPartOfCircularDependency" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="DarkRed" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

The problem that only one of these styles is working at a time, not both of them, how can I work this around?

**Edit** The first style is styling nodes and the second one is styling connectors between these nodes.

Comment: Are you saying that if you comment out the style for NodeBorderStyle, then the style for NodeConnector works, and vice-versa?

Comment: commenting out NodeBorderStyle will throw an exception (Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.) 

When commenting out NodeConnector the connectors aren't visible.

Comment: Can you put your sample application somewhere we can download it?

Comment: here's the whole solution .. http://www.mediafire.com/?jubl2bj6vyf8x8a
2 projects the winforms host and the wpf project.
Graph1.xaml is the file which has the problem.